# the image size is not fit in the slider using easySlider.js 1.5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, size

I am using easyslider.js along with c# asp.net. I tried to work my way around and it still doesn't work. Can you please help me?

Here is my code:

HTML with asp.net

```
<section class="m_main">
  <div id="m_slider">
    <ul>
      @*the sizing issue has been resolved here by defining the div and ul have the same class name*@
      @foreach (var banner in Banner1) {
        <li>
          <a href="@banner.LinkPath"><img src="@Url.Content("~" + GraphicImagePath + banner.LargeImage)" alt="@banner.Description" title="@banner.ImageAlt" /></a>
        </li>
      }
    </ul>
  </div>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
#m_slider ul{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
#m_slider img{
    max-width:100%;
}
```

JS:

```
$("#m_slider").easySlider({
      auto: true,
      speed: 700,
      pause: 5000,
      continuous: true,
    });
```

Comment: What is the size of your images?

Comment: the size of the actual images are 950 by 324.